# What is the order of block hashes in block-locator array?

Tags: protocol

I have to compose a "getblocks" command found in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#getblocks

The "getblocks" command contains the "block locator hashes". In essence, I inform a remote node of block hashes that I'm aware of already. There is a rule of how to construct the block locator. Except I’ve no idea of what “pushing”, “going back” or “newest back” means. I cannot figure out the order of block hashes in what I call a locatorArray.

Let’s assume I want to advertise three block hashes:

- Block hash of block number zero.
- Block hash of block number one.
- Block hash of block number two.

Let’s assume I have an array of three elements. For example, I might walk through the array in a for loop as follows:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < locatorArrayLength; i++ )
{

}
```

The block hash of which block number should be in locatorArray[0]?
The block hash of which block number should be in locatorArray[2]?

Comment: Where did this data come from, the daemon, an API? Some context would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what data you want in locatorArray.

Comment: I've made the statement of my problem more lucid.

Comment: @u2843 Did you read the snippet of code provided alongside the documentation?

Comment: @Nick ODell I didn't read it. I looked at it. I don't know the language it's written in. I've no idea of what's going on in there. I don't need to know the mechanics of the code. All I care about is whether, using my example, the block number zero is in locatorArray[0] and block number two is in locatorArray[2], or block number two is in locatorArray[0] and block number zero is in locatorArray[2].

Answer (score 1):

The code on that wiki page is how Bitcoin Core constructs block locators, and it's a good method, but the method isn't enforced by the protocol. All you need to do is list a bunch of block hashes that you know about, ordered by descending block height. So in your example your locator could be (2,1,0), (2,1), (1), etc., but not (1, 2).